# Cannot read property undefined of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

#### Current Behavior

I am very new to React and pretty much all this stack. What I am trying to accomplish is to implement a tab navigator inside a stack navigator. I've done this without Redux using [React navigation library](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) but I can not do it when I move my stack navigator to Redux. I've even tried a different navigation library and I keep ending up with that error in the title which is driving me crazy because it does not tell much (or I just do not get it).

I've used the exact [Redux example available in the examples repo](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/tree/master/examples). everything works until I change my home screen (the one after login) to a tab navigator I've created.

#### main.js (expo project)

```
import Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './store';
import AppWithNavigationState from './helpers/AppNavigator';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppWithNavigationState />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

Expo.registerRootComponent(App);
```

#### store.js

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import reducers from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    autoRehydrate()
  )
);

// persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage, whitelist: ['likedJobs'] });

export default store;
```

#### helpers/AppNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNavigationHelpers, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from '../screens/auth/LoginScreen';
// import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen'; 
// import HomeRoutes from '../routes/HomeRoutes';
import HomeRoutes from '../helpers/HomeNavigator'; 

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Home: { screen: HomeRoutes }, 
});

const AppWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
  <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })} />
);

AppWithNavigationState.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  nav: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nav: state.nav,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);
```

#### helpers/homeNavigator

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNavigationHelpers, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import CustomerListScreen from '../screens/home/CustomerListScreen'; 
import JobListScreen from '../screens/home/JobListScreen'; 

JobListScreen.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Jobs', 
  title: "Jobs",
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
    <Icon
      name='wrench'
      size={24}
      style={{ color: tintColor }}
    />
  ),
};

CustomerListScreen.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Clients', 
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
    <Icon
      name='users'
      size={24}
      style={{ color: tintColor }}
    />
  ),
};


export const HomeNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Jobs: { 
    screen: JobListScreen, 
   },
  Clients: { 
    screen: CustomerListScreen, 
  } 
});

const HomeNavigationTab = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
  <HomeNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })} />
);

HomeNavigationTab.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  nav: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  homeNav: state.nav,
});

export default HomeNavigationTab;
// export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeNavigationTab);
```

Home tab reducer

```
import { NavigationActions, addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';

import { HomeNavigator } from '../helpers/HomeNavigator';

// Start with two routes: The Main screen, with the Login screen on top.
const firstAction = HomeNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Jobs');
const tempNavState = HomeNavigator.router.getStateForAction(firstAction);
const secondAction = HomeNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Clients');

const initialNavState = HomeNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
  secondAction,
  tempNavState
);

function homeTabNav(state = initialNavState, action) {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'JOBS': 
      nextState = HomeNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Jobs' }),
        state
      );
      break;
    case 'CLIENTS':
      nextState = HomeNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Clients' }),
        state
      );
      break;
    default:
      nextState = HomeNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
      break;
  }

  // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
  return nextState || state;
} 

export default homeTabNav;
```

App navigation reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { NavigationActions, addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';

import { AppNavigator } from '../helpers/AppNavigator';

// Start with two routes: The Main screen, with the Login screen on top.
const firstAction = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Home');
const tempNavState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(firstAction);
const secondAction = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Login');

const initialNavState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
  secondAction,
  tempNavState
);

function nav(state = initialNavState, action) {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'NAV_LOGIN_SUCCESS': 
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.back(),
        state
      );
      break;
    case 'LOGOUT':
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }),
        state
      );
      break;
    default:
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
      break;
  }

  // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
  return nextState || state;
} 

export default nav;
```

#### My Environment

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "expo": "17.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.1.5",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-17.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.13", 
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.0",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong or if this is a bug (I bet that it is me though) and I could use some light.

#### update 1

I've taken off redux from my child navigation (home screen tab nav) and now the error statement has changed to the one below.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `dispatch` is marked as required in `HomeNavigationTab`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Comment: When does the error fire?

Comment: When it loads the screen with the tab router navigation (home) after the login page click event

Comment: Where is the `HomeScreen` file? From your description it sounds like that's likely where the problem lies. Also, does the error give you a file name and line number?

Comment: My guess is that default state isn't defined in the reducer.  When you get an error like `cannot read property undefined of undefined`, it means that you are trying to read a property of an undefined object.  The reason this would happen is that the reducers run once before the being seeded with the state you plan to render.  If you don't define some initial state, you may get an error like that.  What do your reducers look like?

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the time spent for helping out. It is really appreciated. If it makes you feel any better, it is past midnight and I am still trying to figure it out. I've updated the files in the question and also the question itself. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Based on the TabNavigator example [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) you don't actually need to pass in dispatch or nav in the to your component. So remove them and export (or export default)`HomeNavigator` instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import CustomerListScreen from '../screens/home/CustomerListScreen'; 
import JobListScreen from '../screens/home/JobListScreen'; 

JobListScreen.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Jobs', 
  title: "Jobs",
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
    <Icon
      name='wrench'
      size={24}
      style={{ color: tintColor }}
    />
  ),
};

CustomerListScreen.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Clients', 
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
    <Icon
      name='users'
      size={24}
      style={{ color: tintColor }}
    />
  ),
};

export const HomeNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Jobs: { 
    screen: JobListScreen, 
   },
  Clients: { 
    screen: CustomerListScreen, 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was under the impression that the [child navigator component does not need to be hooked up to redux](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) because it gets it from the parent. I've done what you have said and the error has changed to this ```There is no route defined for key Login.
Must be one of: 'Jobs','Clients'``` so it feels like it only cares for my child routes now and ignores what I have set for app navigator (parent) routes

Comment: I've updated my answer. I believe it should work now.